# JNI_CreateJavaVM crashes C++ application without error message

Tags: java, c++, dll, jvm, voce

I want to use Voce in a C++ application. Now, in the voce header, more specifically the `void init()` there's a part like this:

```
vm_args.nOptions = 2;
// Setup the VM options.
// TODO: check out other options to be used here, like disabling the 
// JIT compiler.
JavaVMOption options[2];
// Add the required Java class paths.
std::string classPathString = "-Djava.class.path=";
classPathString += vocePath;
classPathString += "/voce.jar";
char s[1024];
sprintf(s, classPathString.c_str());
options[0].optionString = s;
options[0].extraInfo = NULL;

// Add an option to increase the max heap size. (1)
char x[1024] = "-Xmx256m";
options[1].optionString = x;
options[1].extraInfo = NULL;
//options[1].optionString = "-Djava.compiler=NONE"; // Disable JIT.
//options[1].optionString = "-verbose:gc,class,jni";
vm_args.options = options;
//vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_FALSE;

// Create the VM. (2)
status = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&internal::gJVM, (void**)&internal::gEnv, &vm_args);
```

If I try to run it like this, it crashes. If I put everything in a comment after (1), it runs. After that, if I just put the JNI_CreateJavaVM in a comment (2), it runs as well. If I go straight from the crashing to just putting (2) in a comment, it crashes again. I need to take the path over (1) and (2), then just (2). However, since Voce needs that JavaVM, this is a problem. Apparently. My guess would be, that I need some dll, at the moment I have the jvm.dll in the same folder as main.cpp, but not the same as voce.h.

Answer (score 0):

If you use dynamic linking and loading for the installed jvm.dll, this should work.

```
typedef jint(JNICALL *pCreateJavaVM)(JavaVM **, void**, void *);

HINSTANCE hInstance = LoadLibrary(L"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_77\\bin\\server\\jvm.dll");
pCreateJavaVM CreateJavaVM = (pCreateJavaVM)GetProcAddress(hInstance, "JNI_CreateJavaVM");

jint res = CreateJavaVM(&vm, (void **)&env, &vm_args);
```